# Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

I can't get the legend for my barplot to appear.

```
table1b <- table(mydata$SEX, mydata$CLASS)
addmargins(table1b)
colorSex <- c("lightpink", "gray", "lightblue")
barplot(table1b, beside = TRUE, 
    ylab ="Frequency", ylim = c(0, 150), axes = TRUE,
    xlab = "Class", col = colorSex,
    main = "Abalones Class by Gender")
legend("topleft", c("Female", "Intersex", "Male"), cex=0.8, fill=colorSex)
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: Do you realize `addmargins` does not operate in side-effect? That call is being ignored. Other than that, lacking your `mydata`, I cannot reproduce your error (I can do it with `table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)`). I suggest you add a representative sample with the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a good sampling from `mydata`. Alternatively, `dput(table1b)` should work too.

Comment: I can get it to work if I open a new file, but it just won't work in the one I'm in.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"open a new file"*, so there might be more than what you have communicated in your question. Again, if you add the output from `dput(table1b)`, more might become clear. Without that and/or other significant updates to the question, I don't know what's wrong as I have not figured out what to do to the data to get your error.